# How to download a text/json file from any browser that contains data in json format

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, json

I want to download a text/json file using string that contains the data in json format.

I am adding a ArrayList containing the a object of Service Class to the model from controller. Below is the code.

```
 @RequestMapping("/Application.html")

 public ModelAndView getdetails() throws Exception {

      ArrayList<Service> servicesList = new ArrayList<Service>();
      ServiceBean service=new ServiceBean();    // This is bean class

      String jsonData = "{\"menu\": {  \"id\": \"file\",  \"value\": \"File\",  \"popup\": {    \"menuitem\": [      {\"value\": \"New\", \"onclick\": \"CreateNewDoc()\"},      {\"value\": \"Open\", \"onclick\": \"OpenDoc()\"},    ]  }}}";
      service.setJsonData(jsonData);
      servicesList.add(service);


      ServiceBean service=new ServiceBean();    // This is bean class
      String jsonData = "{    version-info: {        minVersion: 2.0.1,        currentVersion: 2.0.1,        configuration: {            id: {},            language: {},            url: {},            version: 2.0.1        },        clientApp: ABC    }}";
      service.setJsonData(jsonData);
      servicesList.add(service);

      ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("showVersion");
      mav.addObject("servicesList",servicesList);

 }
```

Now I want to download each jsonData file.

```
 <button>Download First File</button>
 <button>Download Second File</button>
```

On Clicking any button a text/json file containing the relevant data should download.

And the data in file should be in proper JSON format like:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

I am unable to retrieve the data in JSON format. please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
$json = json_encode( array( 'test' => 'test' ));

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=jsonFile.json');
header('Content-type: application/json');

echo( $json);
```